# HTML5 streaming video - is it possible?

Tags: video, html

Is it possible to use HTML5's *video* tag and connect it to an RMTP stream? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Although the HTML5 video specs don't define what codecs should be used, currently browsers only support H.264 and WebM.

RTMP uses a different codec, so no, it's not supported by any browser, as of 3Q/2010. (also, RTSP is a protocol that works *beside* HTTP, not on top of it. RTSPT ("RTSP over HTTP") could be theoretically supported in the future or through some sort of plugin, but it's unlikely to happen)

Comment: Thanks, Piskvor. What about using something like XML playlists that tell the HTML5 video player, via JavaScript, what to play next? This won't qualify as streaming, but it will work on handhelds.

Also, what's the HTML5 video streaming that the folks at BrightCove.com talk about?

Comment: @Alex: I have no idea what the folks at BrightCove.com told you, but their "video platform" seems to be a custom Flash player (at least at a first glance). The playlist idea sounds workable, although you'd probably have to switch the `video` tags yourself through JS.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought :)

Comment: @Alex-Can you elaborate more on your playlist design?